# Doctrine migrations для postgres

Tags: postgresql, doctrine2

Пытаюсь прикрутить Doctrine migrations. Создал вот такую структуру файлов: [image: структehf]

Вроде все подключается, пустая миграция создается, но при применении миграции получаю ошибку

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                               
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE migrations (version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(version))':  
  SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 РћРЁР�Р‘РљРђ:  СЃС…РµРјР° РґР»СЏ СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ РѕР±СЉРµРєС‚РѕРІ РЅРµ РІС‹Р±СЂР°РЅР°                                 
  LINE 1: CREATE TABLE migrations (version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIM...
```

Файл конфига подключения migrations-db.php выглядит так:

```
<?php
return array(
    'dbname'   => 'lk',
    'user'     => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'pgadmin',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'driver'   => 'pdo_pgsql',
);
```

Сам класс миграции, который пытаюсь применить

```
<?php

namespace ExampleMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20171208114543 extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $myTable = $schema->createTable('artists');
        $myTable->addColumn('id', 'integer',
            ['unsigned' => true, 'autoincrement'=>true]);
        $myTable->addColumn('name', 'string', ['length' => 60]);
        $myTable->setPrimaryKey(['id']);

    }

    /**
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        $schema->dropTable('artists');
    }
}
```

Сами таблицы лежат в БД lk и схеме lk. Прбовал добавить схему в файл конфига подключения, но ничего не вышло. Подскажите, как это решить

Comment: Как добавляли? Ошибка была та же? Что в логах самого postgresql?

Comment: И еще до кучи содержимое migrations/DoctrineMigrations
Что бы понимать что файлы для миграции сгенирировались как нужно